# How to find the address of variable in a memory hexdump?

Tags: c, gdb, hex, memory-address

While I was doing "Learn C The Hard Way" examples, I thought to myself:

> I set int a = 10; but where does that value 10 actually? Can I access it manually from the outside while my program is running?

*Here's a little C code snippet for demonstration purposes:*

```
int main (int argc, char const* argv[]) {                                   

    int a = 10;
    int b = 5;
    int c = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

I opened up the [The GNU Project Debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) (GDB) and entered:

```
break main
run
next 2
```

From what I understood **0x7fff5bffb04** is a *memory address* of `int c`. I then used **hexdump -C /dev/mem** system call to dump the entire memory into the terminal.

Now the question is where do I look for the *variable c* in this massive hex dump? My hope is that given the address `0x7fff5bffb04` I can find its value, which is `15`. Also, bonus question, what does each column in **hexdump -C** represent? (I know the last column is ASCII representation)

[image: gdb]

[image: hex dump]

Comment: The `0x7f...` address is virtual. You can't use it to locate stuff in a physical memory dump unless you know the virtual->physical mapping. (First column is "address" (n° of bytes since start of file), last is ascii representation, middle is the data.)

Comment: @Mat: Thanks. Can I print the physical memory address, or can I hex dump virtual memory instead of physical memory? What is a possible solution?

Comment: Why did you define `argv` to be `char const *[]`?

Comment: @TwilightPonyInc.: nothing practical (you need kernel code for that). "What is a possible solution?" - it's not clear what your actual problem is. If you're trying to make sense of a raw full-system memory dump, you're facing a very complex task. Depending on what exactly you're trying to do there may be things to make it simpler.

Comment: Instead of using /dev/mem, use /proc/pid/mem, where _pid_ is the ID of the process running your program (note: NOT the gdb process).

Comment: @Barmar: I will try that later when I reboot into Ubuntu 12.10. Mac OS X does not have `proc`.

Comment: You can use the gcore program from http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter8/core/download/gcore-1.3.tar.gz to make a process core dump in OS X.

Comment: What about using `gcc`'s `x` command to dump memory? It also takes a format specifier. This also let's you dump the data in hex format (if this is what you like to see).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I then used hexdump -C /dev/mem system call to dump the entire memory into the terminal.

Your hexdump dumped physical memory addresses. The address `0x7fff5bffb04` is a *virtual* address of the variable in the process you are debugging. It is mapped to some *physical* address, but you will not be able to find which without examining kernel mapping tables (as Mat already told you in a comment).

To examine virtual address space, use `/proc/<pid>/mem` (as Barmar already told you in a comment).

But this entire exercise is *pointless*, because you *already* can examine the virtual memory in GDB, and you are not going to see *anything* when you look at virtual memory that GDB didn't already show you much more conveniently [1].

[1] Except you could see GDB-inserted breakpoints, but you are not expected to understand that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no reason why the values would even exist in ram. More than Likly the machine code for this program simply has the values in cpu registers. You would have to have more bytes (try at least 512) and set them to a random value, which you could then search for in the memory dump.

You are far better of looking at the assembly code produced by the c compiler.

Comment: "there is no reason why the values would even exist in ram" -- yes, there is. When the program is built without optimization (as is the case here), most compilers will reserve space on stack, and will *actually* save the values there. And if the program is built *with* optimization, then there is no reason for the values to exist in registers either: any decent compiler will optimize all of the assignments away, since their results are not used.